# Multiplication in the wavelet domain, what does it look like in real space?

Tags: wavelet

Say you wavelet transform a signal, multiply by some values, and untransform. Is there anything we can say about the effect in real space? I know that it's not exactly a convolution, because the convolution theorem doesn't really exist for the wavelet transform. So if it's not a convolution, what is it?

Also, is the effect different if you multiply in an *orthogonal* wavelet basis (at, say, dyadic frequencies) versus a continuous transform at all frequencies?

Answer (score 2):

They can be  used for time-varying filtering of non-stationary signals, under names like Gabor multipliers, STFT filters for instance.  You can find a review reference in the chapter [Linear Time-Frequency Filters, 11.1.3 Implicit design](http://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/pub-et_7981.pdf) and generalization in [Spreading function representation of operators and Gabor multiplier approximation](http://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/open_files/5084_DT_STSIP.pdf).

You also have the 2004 paper [The convolution theorem for the continuous wavelet transform](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168403002159). My  experience in this domain is limited to localized matched filtering, by  multiplying coefficients by scalar complex numbers to locally modify amplitude and phase (with complex continuous wavelet frames), see [Adaptive multiple subtraction with wavelet-based complex unary Wiener filters](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.4674.pdf).

The redundancy of the continuous transform certainly helps a lot. With DWT (a variant of them) I have also used  masks to remove localized high amplitude disturbances in some discrete wavelet subbands. The masks were initially binary ($0$ on the places to remove, $1$ outside), but they were tapered to have a smooth profile between $0$ and $1$. Not very theoretical, but efficient to separate directional data.

Finally, you can find across-scale multiplication for [ROI (region-of interest) coding with JPEG 2000](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~fstentif/DICTA02.pdf).

Comment: Hi, thanks! I ask because I want to model 3D data with a covariance that's diagonal in wavelet space. I'm struggling to understand how multiplying wavelet basis functions affects the structure in real space.

Comment: @cgreen aside from the experience that Laurent brought in (really awesome!) a good trick is to really write down what you're doing with respect to formalized methods – in this case, linear algebra, representing the DWT as linear operators, ie. matrix multiplications. That way, point-wise multiplication can often also be understood as diagonal matrix – and, depending on the structure of the wavelet you're actually looking at, this might be sufficient or not to make the statements you need.