# Wavelet transform of a spatial convolution

Tags: convolution, wavelet, dwt

Does anyone know if there exist a kind of convolution theorem for the discrete wavelet transform (decimated or undecimated)?

In other words can I find a simple form of
$W\left[ \int f(t) g(x-t) \, dt\right] $ where $W$ is the discrete wavelet transform operator?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say I have a clear understanding of this at this time.  However, a few pointers. I'd love to see somebody provide a detailed account. Others bits at: [Multiplication in the wavelet domain, what does it look like in real space?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/31590/15892)

- The nonexistence of a wavelet function admitting a wavelet convoluton theorem of the Fourier type, 1994, A. R. Lindsey, unpublished report
- [Convolution using the undecimated discrete wavelet transform](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICASSP.1996.543662), 1996

> Convolution is one of the most widely used digital signal processing
>   operations. It can be implemented using the fast Fourier transform
>   (FFT), with a computationalcomplexity of $O(N \log N)$. The
>   undecimated discrete wavelet transform (UDWT) is linear and shift
>   invariant, so it can also be used to implement convolution. In this
>   paper, we propose a scheme to implement the convolution using the
>   UDWT, and study its advantages and limitations.

- [Convolution theorems for linear transforms](https://doi.org/10.1109/78.720385), 1998

> This correspondence explores the existence of convolution theorem for
>   linear transformations under a variety of different assumptions. There
>   are eight convolution theorems, all Fourier-related with only N
>   operations in the transform domain and no ordering constraints on the
>   convolution components in the result. They include circular
>   convolutions and correlations.

- [The convolution theorem for the continuous wavelet tranform](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.sigpro.2003.07.014), 2004

> We study the application of the continuous wavelet transform to
>   perform signal filtering processes. We first show that the convolution
>   and correlation of two wavelet functions satisfy the required
>   admissibility and regularity conditions. By using these new wavelet
>   functions to analyze both convolutions and correlations, respectively,
>   we derive convolution and correlation theorems for the continuous
>   wavelet transform and show them to be similar to that of other joint
>   spatial/spatial–frequency or time/frequency representations. We then
>   investigate the effect of multiplying the continuous wavelet transform
>   of a given signal by a related transfer function and show how to
>   perform spatially variant filtering operations in the wavelet domain.
>   Finally, we present numerical examples showing the usefulness of
>   applying the convolution theorem for the continuous wavelet transform
>   to perform signal restoration in the presence of additive noise.

- [On the uniqueness of the convolution theorem for the Fourier transform](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.48.9577&rep=rep1&type=pdf), 2008

> This paper shows that members of the fourier transform family are the
>   only linear transforms that have a convolution theorem, that is, that
>   can replace $O(N^2)$ operations of a convolution in a time domain by
>   $O(N)$ operations in a transform domain. Generally, there is an
>   additional cost to compute the transform itself. Our observation is
>   motivated by recent activity in wavelet and subband decompositions and
>   related spectral analyses, which are attractive alternatives for
>   signal compression applications. A natural question when using such
>   techniques is to determine if convolutions of $N$-point signals can be
>   calculated with fewer operations in a compressed transform domain than
>   in an uncompressed time domain. The answer is negative for a broad set
>   of assumptions. This paper indicates what assumptions must be relaxed
>   in seeking a linear transform that has a convolution theorem
>   comparable to the convolution theorem for Fourier transforms.